# Why wasn't Arlong in Impel Down during the Impel Down Saga?

Tags: one-piece

He was a known member of Fisher Tiger's crew and became a merciless dictator in East Blue. He had the highest bounty in East Blue at the time, and when Borsalino captured him, he was sent to Impel Down. So why was he not there during the big jail break?

I doubt he got left behind, because Buggy did most of the freeing of prisoners.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We currently have the following timeline of things happening to Arlong:

1. Arlong gets beaten by Borsalino (Kizaru) and sent to Impel Down.
2. Arlong is released from Impel Down when Jinbe became a Shichibukai.
3. Arlong had a fight with Jinbe and started the [Arlong Pirates](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Arlong_Pirates) and went to East Blue and settled on [Cocoyasi Island](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Conomi_Islands).
4. Luffy and crew follow Nami to Cocoyasi Island where Luffy beats up Arlong.
5. All of Arlong's crew get arrested (exception: [Hatchan](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Hatchan)) by marines.

I skipped a large chunk between points 3 and 4 because it's irrelevant. You can find all of Arlong's history [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Arlong#History).

At point 5 when they got arrested you would assume that he would have been sent to Impel Down again, but it is futher unknown what has happened to Arlong as it hasn't been shown or told in the anime or manga.

Comment: Don't forget, Hatchan got arrested but he escaped

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what happened to Arlong, but according to Hodi Jones he was killed by humans...

[image: From chapter 634]

<sup>From chapter 634</sup>

And from the Anime Episode #554:

[image: From Episode #554 screenshot 1]
[image: From Episode #554 screenshot 2]

Comment: But that looks like a meme!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Arlong was released earlier on Jinbes request.

Source: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Arlong#After_Tiger.27s_Death
http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Impel_Down#Prisoners

Comment: you are right one that he was released on Jinbe's request but this all happened before the impel down saga. arlong got arrested again on cocoyashi island and it is unknown where he is now

Comment: And he got recaptured though.

Answer (score 0):

the implication (that will never be confirmed or denied because either way raises plot holes) is that he was killed during his battle with Luffy. That's what Hordy is referencing, I believe.

Comment: You can expand on your answer by adding some details to why this would create plot holes to better support the claim that he was killed in battle